# Wi-Fi settings grayed out on iPhone

Tags: wifi, iphone

When I go into **Setting / Wifi** and try to turn Wifi on, it does not let me. The *switch* is grayed out.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: thanks but that doesn't work and my wifi says no wifi

Comment: So you're actually able of turning Wifi **on**?

Answer (score 1):

this is the only guide that worked for me : http://smarttechtips.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-fix-grayed-out-wifi-on-iphone.html

**here is a summary of what you are going to do :D :**

- you will have to jailbreak your device first.
- enable cellular data and install openSSH, afc2add (those 2 apps are around 4  megabytes only)
- install an app called ispirit on your pc and then connect your device.
- install macfixer on your phone using ispirit , then restart cydia and install essential updates
  (you will find an update for macfixer, install it )
- restart your phone.
- if this didn't work then try the hair dryer method first , (only heat the specified parts for 3-4 minutes or till you get the message that says 'your phone is too hot....') then reapply this guide again.
  hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could try:

- Restarting your iPhone.
- Reseting the network settings on **Settings / General / Reset / Reset Network Settings**. This will reset all network settings, including Bluetooth pairing records, Wi-Fi passwords, VPN, and APN settings.
- Back up the device and then restore the firmware and software from iTunes

If none of these work, it's probably a hardware issue and you should [contact Apple](http://www.apple.com/support/contact/) support.